# Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version

Tags: magento-1.7, error, php-5.2.x.x

I getting php version error message in my site.

I have two magento instance in same server, One is ruining & another  is not running. Please share idea/answer with me.

Comment: you may using older version of php. check it using `phpinfo()`

Comment: but same code also run on another instance. I just replace the into another instance it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see it could be one of the following things:

1) Corrupt index.php in your magento root dir.

2) Incorrect virtual host set up resulting in php not executing the code in index.php

Could you post your apache site configuation and or your index.php

Comment: At first I replaced default index.php & index.php.sample. There are same error.

Comment: Did you check your web server configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the source of the page you will see the entire index.php file listed. it happens the same if you call `cron.php`. This makes me thing that you don't have php installed on the subdomain `staging.`.